# post call to a php function

Tags: php, jquery

ok what im doing is using onmousedown to call my javascript function this function then sets a php variable to a form depending on what i send. how do i get what is returned from php script back to the the orginal script so it can be displayed in an a drop down using

```
function toggleInteractContainers(x) 
{
  if ($('#'+x).is(":hidden")) {
   $('#'+x).slideDown(200);
  } else {
   $('#'+x).hide();
  }
  $('.interactContainers').hide();
}
```

the html is

```
<div class="interactContainers" id="edit_venue">       
    <?php echo $display_edit_form; ?>  
</div>
```

the script is

```
if ($_POST["request"] == "edit_now")
 {

  $display_edit_form =' 
   <form action="" method="post" name="venue_edit">
             <table width="90%" border="1" cellspacing="5" cellpadding="5">
                  <tr>
                    <td width="20px"><?php echo $id ?></td>
                    <td align="right">Venue Name :</td>
                    <td align="left"><input name="venue" type="text"></td>
                  </tr>
                </table>
   <input name="submit" type="submit" value="submit">
            </form>';
  return $display_edit_form;  
 }
```

i just need a javascript to call the post and get the $display_edit_form back then set it to a php Var

I hope i gave you enough info to give me an answer

Comment: Rodney, please format your code as code by indenting it with 4 spaces (or use the 101010 button on selected text), otherwise it's unreadable.

Comment: I'd suggest you learn something about AJAX: http://w3schools.com/ajax/default.asp

Comment: @deceze: oh, I never "seen" that 101010 button and always formatted all sources manually here or in my notepad :-S

Comment: @zerk Even _you_‽ In case you're serious, Jeff seriously needs to do something about the visibility of that button.

Comment: @deceze: yes. It was a lot of pain to format sql in pony-style with millions presses of space button. Btw, I've seen it is a button but haven't idea what is it for and did not want to discover it. Meanwhile I've used link, quote, and picture buttons a lot of times. :-)

Comment: OK that's nice 5 reply's and not 1 answer. usually w3schools is really good but that was a whole lot of nothing!

Comment: @Rodney - I would like to help you, but you need to explain a little more explicitly. Which variable do you want to send back to your server. The code sample that you gave is a little incomplete.

Comment: but realy all i need to know is how i know how to use the jquery$.post to run a php script and stuff just not how to recive it on the return

Answer (score 0):

if I understand correctly you need to make an ajax call and then append the HTMLresponse into your interactContainer div (not using php echo out)

Comment: im using a php echo all i ned to know is how to get the var from the javascript to php i know it can be done just not shure how

Comment: I found something that works but the problem is it runs the script b4 i open the container. if i use an if statement it keeps the box hidden but dose not run the script when the box is opened  do i need to use the document rdy function or is there a way around it?